# Access to methods of a static instance by multiple threads

Tags: java, multithreading

- Let's say I've created a `final static` instance of the class
  [`ComparatorChain`](https://commons.apache.org/collections/api-3.1/org/apache/commons/collections/comparators/ComparatorChain.html).
- Through [`Collections.sort(List<T> list, Comparator<? super T> c)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#sort%28java.util.List,%20java.util.Comparator%29) I'm using this instance.
- Somewhere in `Collections.sort(List<T> list, Comparator<? super T> c)` [`Comparator.compare(T o1, T o2)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) is called on the `ComparatorChain` instance.

**Now my beginners question:**

When multiple threads use this static instance can they all call the `Comparator.compare(T o1, T o2)` method at the same time?

I'd suppose that as long as there is no `synchronized` modifier involved, they could. Is this right?

**Why do I want to know this?**

Through such a `static` instance I could avoid the useless creation of `ComparatorChain` objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, if there's no synchronization involved, there's nothing to stop multiple threads calling the same method multiple times concurrently - whether that's a static method or an instance method on an object which is accessible by multiple threads, *however* it's accessible by those threads.

It's worth noting that although a *variable* can be static, there's no such concept as a static *object*. While on this occasion I knew what you meant, the difference between a variable and an object is often vital.

So long as your `ComparatorChain.compare` method is thread-safe, it sounds like you should be fine. Most comparisons *can* easily be thread-safe, as they rarely mutate state.

Answer (score 0):

It is fine to use one instance ([singleton](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern)) as long as:

- you don't store anything in instance fields
- there's no `synchronized` (it will work, but will block and make things slow)

An example of that is `java.lang.String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER` - a `static` comparator

Answer (score 0):

After reading source code of `ComparatorChain`, I find it's stateful and not thread-safe if multi-Thread access the `ComparatorChain` instance.

Comment: "Instances of ComparatorChain are not synchronized. The class is not thread-safe at construction time, but it is thread-safe to perform multiple comparisons after all the setup operations are complete." https://commons.apache.org/collections/apidocs/org/apache/commons/collections/comparators/ComparatorChain.html